# How to add multiple extensions to selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

How to add multiple extensions to selenium chrome webdriver?

I tryed add extensions using comma, but getting errors

```
chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension.crx',r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension1.crx',,r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension3.crx')
```

but getting errors

My working code with one extension:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import gmtime, strftime
from os import system
import pyperclip
import datetime
import time
import os
import sys



executable_path = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(4)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/gK6Rq0UH/")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="footer-chart-panel"]/div[2]/span[4]""").click()
time.sleep(4)
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bottom-area"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]""").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    contents = pyperclip.paste()
    time.sleep(2)
    filepath = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DATA.txt"
    time.sleep(2)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
        f.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each **extension** you want to add you have to call `chrome_options.add_extension` like this:

```
chrome_options.add_extension('Path/to/extension/one')
chrome_options.add_extension('Path/to/extension/two')
```

Comment: chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension.crx')
chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension1.crx')                                                                     
                                                                                                        ..................      dont work, error in secord string

Comment: That image does not give me much information, I'm going to assume the string you are passing is an invalid path.

Comment: Can you copy the path from **explorer** directly and post it?