# How to open brave browser with extensions? Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying open Brave browser, but every time this happen, browser open without any extensions, which I have if I open browser normally. Why this happen and what can I do to open this with extensions I need?

I tried open this, so there is code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "C:/Users/User1/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple extensions to selenium chrome webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311344/how-to-add-multiple-extensions-to-selenium-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: I get the path of extension, for example there will be "...BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Extensions\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn\10.20.0_0" but which file in folder extension I should take?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the extension as a crx-file, then declare it in your chromeoptions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
add_block_ext = "Path to .crx extension"
driver_path = "C:/Users/User1/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
option.add_extension(add_block_ext)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Or directly in between the parentes option.add_extension("PATH_TO_EXTENSION")